Validity of a Tauberian theorem for Dirichlet series
I encountered this statement about Dirichlet series but couldn't find a similar result in Korevaar's "Tauberian Theory". Is this statement valid?
Statement:
Let $f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ be a Dirichlet series, where $a_n$ are real numbers.
Suppose:

Analyticity and simple pole: $f(s)$ is analytic in $\Re(s) > \sigma_0$, except at $s = \sigma_0$, where it has a simple pole with residue $r$.
Growth control: There exists $\kappa \geq 0$ such that for $\sigma \geq \sigma_0$ and $|t| \to \infty$:
$|f(\sigma + it)| \leq C |t|^{\kappa},$
where $C > 0$ is constant.

Conclusion:
As $x \to \infty$:
$$A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} a_n = \frac{r x^{\sigma_0}}{\sigma_0} + o\left( x^{\sigma_0} \right).$$
Is this correct? If so, what is a reference for the proof? The result seems more general than expected, as it doesn't require $a_n$ to be positive.

Where did you encounter this statement? A reference could help people answer your question.

This statement is supposedly due to Ingham. I don't have access to Ingham's original papers and couldn't find this exact result in Korevaar's "Tauberian Theory" or other accessible sources. Can anyone confirm if this is indeed Ingham's theorem and provide a reference (or not)?

I would recommend reading Delange's Tauberian theorem, it is a bit easier to apply, but requires slightly stronger hypotheses

Thank you for the suggestion. While Delange's theorem is indeed valuable, it requires non-negative coefficients. The statement I'm inquiring about allows for any real a(n), which is why I'm particularly interested in verifying its validity and origin. This generality is the key aspect of my question.

where did you see this? I highly, highly doubt such a thing is true since for example it would eliminate a counterexample to RH where there is precisely one simple zero with maximal real part say $1/2< \delta<1$; then $1/\zeta$ would satisfy your hypothesis (since it is known and easy to prove that its abscissa of convergence is the supremum of the real parts of the zeroes, while the control on vertical lines is also well known to follow) but the summatory function of the Mobius function (the Mertens function) is known to oscillate so cannot have an asymptotic

Thank you for your insight. If I'm not mistaken: If $\rho=\sigma+it$ is a zero of $\zeta(s)$ with $\frac{1}{2}<\sigma<1$, then its complex conjugate $\overline{\rho}=\sigma-it$ is also a zero. These paired zeros would contribute terms to the asymptotic of the form $\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho\zeta'(\rho)}+\frac{x^{\overline{\rho}}}{\overline{\rho}\zeta'(\overline{\rho})}$. This indeed generates oscillations due to the $x^{it}$ term. However, this doesn't necessarily contradict the "statement" which specifies a pole on the real line.

Well then what about a real character $L$ function having a simple zero on the real line between $1/2$ and $1$ with maximal real part and taking $1/L$
